# error: could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic

Tags: scala, shapeless

Wrote this simple code for shapeless which does not work

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val genPerson = Generic[Person]
```

But get compile error

```
<console>:21: error: could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic[Person]
       val genPerson = Generic[Person]
```

Comment: That should work as is. My hunch is that you're using Scala 2.10.x but haven't added macro-paradise to your build.

Comment: That worked!!! My SBT Console was running Scala 2.10. You are spot on!